# Android Software Back Button Not Returning To Previous View

Tags: android

I've been looking for over a month and I cannot get this resolved anywhere. Whenever I hit the back button my app closes. I've searched for `finish()` I've overridden the `onBackPressed()`, I just cannot seem to solve this issue.

```
public class Toasty extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_toasty);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Here's your toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_toast);
          }
    });
  }
}
```

This is pretty much all I do. It pops up on the next screen with a text view and a Toast pops up. Then I press that back button and the app exits when all I want to do is reset so that the button can be pressed again.

Comment: "Whenever I hit the back button my app closes." You mean, it crashes? Or it just closes? Because, if it closes... that's the intended behavior since, y'know, you only have one activity. If it crashes, post the logs, please.

Comment: You say you've overriden on back pressed. That's not reflected in your code. I think your question needs a little more clarity. Are you getting an error?

Comment: No it doesn't crash, it just closes. When I re-enter the app (by pressing the launcher icon) it starts over again instead of returning to the second activity.

Also, I have tried overriding "onBackPressed" in previous iterations of the code. This is my most recent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Not returning to previous view"

This is because when you press the back button it doesn't leave a view, it leaves an Activity.

Hence if you have one Activity it will exit the application, no matter how many times you change the view.

To change the behaviour either:

A. Create a new Activity with your second view and go to it via an Intent

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

NOTE: ActivityTwo will be an activity containing R.layout.activity_toasty as its view

B. Override the back button as below

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
     if(currentViewIsShowToast){
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_toasty);
         //Change activity to previous view
     }
     else 
         super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: This has two activities and I am moving to the second by using "setContentView". I've tried B before to no avail.

I'll see if I can get A to work.

Comment: Okay I think you don't understand something. The setContentView method is not for changing activities its for switching views. Use intents that

Comment: Looks like intents did the trick. I just hadn't been able to figure them out until now, thanks.